# Titanium : Camera crashes the application

Tags: image, crash, camera, titanium, store

I am using Titanium sdk's openCamera function to capture an image and storing it to sdcard.

```
function captureImage() {
        var capturedImg;  
        Titanium.Media.showCamera({ 
            success : function(event) {                 
                /* Holds the captured image */
                capturedImg = event.media;

                /* Condition to check the selected media */
                if (event.mediaType == Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO) {
                        var window1 = Project.AddDocumentSaveView.init(capturedImg, docImgModel);
                        window1.oldWindow = win;
                        Project.UI.Common.CommonViews.addWindowToTabGroup(window1);
                        activityInd.hide();

             }
            },
            cancel : function() {

            },
            error : function(error) {
                /* called when there's an error */
                var a = Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({
                    titleid : Project.StringConstant.IMP_DOCS_CAMERA
                });

                if (error.code == Titanium.Media.NO_CAMERA) {
                    a.setMessage(Project.StringConstant.IMP_DOCS_ERROR_WITH_CAMERA);
                } else {
                    a.setMessage(Project.StringConstant.UNEXPECTED_ERROR + error.message);
                }

                a.show();
        }
        });
    }
```

It works fine in iphone and even samsung galaxy s2. But on one device, Motorola Milestone device, the application crashes when the picture is accepted after capturing.

Here is the log while the device was attached : [Log for camera crash](http://pastebin.com/rPdwcvk4)

I tried so many times but couldnt find the issue .I think its some memory issue but i am not sure.

Could someone look into it and help me find what the issue is.

Any help/suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This issue still exists - at least on my Samsung S3 and Moto G (2nd Gen). There a lots of Jira issues about it but no real solution. Did you manage to use the camera reliably?

Answer (score 0):

everything in this block should be done after the camera is close

```
if (event.mediaType == Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO) {
}
```

the camera is memory intensive and you are opening new windows and doing a bunch of other stuff... not good.

Comment: Hey Aaron,
thanks for suggestion... i will try to implement it ...
but m just curious .. are you just suggesting the for the cleanness of the code ...or as a solution to the problem ..

Answer (score 0):

This is an aging issue on Titanium ([TIMOB-12848](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-12848)

On some devices the native camera app (Titanium calls it using an Intent) cause Android to destroy our app.
When it tries to restart it, there's no recovering of the previous state so the intent callback is not called.

I've found a simple workaround to minimize this issue but doesn't resolve it. It just "mask" it somehow.

The workaround is discussed in the previous link and the full example code is [here](https://gist.github.com/xcash/e0e363e04999ba9c8ad2)